# Toilet supply line/tube sprays water from below the coupling nut

Tags: leak, toilet

My toilet tank was leaking rust and water, so I replaced the three bolts at the bottom of the tank.

But when I replaced the supply line/tube, the new supply line/tube sprays water from below the coupling nut. See the picture.

[image]

How do I correctly install the supply tube?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice action photo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the supply flex and make sure there is not an old rubber cone washer squished up into the fill valve, leftover from the old supply line.

Inspect the new line while it is unattached to ensure the washer/gasket/o-ring is in place and undamaged.

Reattach using minimal torque, hand-tight should be enough (with maybe just a bit extra on it with pliers...), do not over-tighten.

Comment: Also, I see a gob of teflon tape on the fill-valve threads. Take all of it off, it is not necessary and will cause leaks. Teflon tape is used on *tapered thread* fittings, which this is not.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I removed the tape from the fill-valve threads. That stopped the leak. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It almost looks like the spray is coming from the crimp of that fitting - if so, it's compromised and needs replaced.  However if it's truly coming from the plastic nut then you just have a bad seal.  As Jimmy said, remove the white teflon tape. They normally have a rubber gasket just like you'd see on a garden hose end that will make the seal for you.

Goodluck! Looks like an easy fix!